# Review queue icons bug

Tags: bug, review, design, information-display

I just noticed today in the review queue (I saw it in GD.SE and M&TV.SE) that the user icons dropped below the correspondent review queue instead of being on the right side in the same row. That makes the screen unnecessary long.

[image]

Comment: @Xufox damn true...